# How do I find out which version of angular-cli a version of nodejs support?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, node-modules

I'm using nodejs v8.8.1 and angular-cli v6.0.8 and I got this error:

> You are running version v8.8.1 of Node.js, which is not supported by
>   Angular CLI v6. The official Node.js version that is supported is 8.9
>   and greater.

If I'm going to install a different version of angular-cli, how can I check which version is supported by nodejs v8.8.1?
I cannot do it the other way around since I have to use nodejs v8.8.1.

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR**: If you can't use any other version of node, it looks like you should use `v5`.

---

What I did was clone the [`angular-cli`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) repo and then ran:

```
git log --oneline -p -L 48,48:package.json --diff-filter=m
```

- `--oneline` to show only the short log of the commit
- `-p` to generate a patch listing
- `-L 48,48:package.json` which is the current line the node version is set on in `package.json` as of commit [`7924e0a`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/7924e0a45545fbff3d117661388a414b7d245873)
- `--diff-filter=m` to show only file modification (although that probably doesn't matter here)

which produced the log listing below.  This shows every time the explicit `node` version requirement changed in the `package.json` `engine` properties.

As you can see it was changed 3 times:

- [`c38b5c09`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/c38b5c09) it was explicitly set to `node >= 4.1.0`
- [`08af5d54`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/08af5d54) it was unchanged, but an explicit `npm` version was set (`npm >=3.0.0`)
- [`0a1f19ff`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/0a1f19ff) it was set to `node >= 6.9.0`
- [`29338bca`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/29338bca) it was set to `node >= 8.9.0`

So, from that, you can assume that you can use any version of Angular from before that commit *should* work.  That particular commit is for the `v6.0.0-beta3`.  So I would say major version `v5`.

**`git log` output**

```
29338bca refactor: set minimum node version to 8.9

diff --git a/package.json b/package.json
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@ -34,2 +34,1 @@
-    "node": ">= 6.9.0",
-    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
+    "node": ">= 8.9.0",
0a1f19ff build: specify package node v6 engine dependency

diff --git a/package.json b/package.json
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@ -32,2 +32,2 @@
-    "node": ">= 4.1.0",
+    "node": ">= 6.9.0",
     "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
08af5d54 chore: add engine entries to package.json

diff --git a/package.json b/package.json
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@ -33,1 +33,2 @@
-    "node": ">= 4.1.0"
+    "node": ">= 4.1.0",
+    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
c38b5c09 chore(deps): make node 4.1.0 requirement explicit

diff --git a/package.json b/package.json
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@ -18,0 +19,1 @@
+    "node": ">= 4.1.0"
```